# Permission Middleware with Laravel 6.6 working on all routes

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

Hi I am working on laravel project ,  I have to check about user's permission when he trying to access  one page , my problem is after I created Permission middle ware , and add it in the kernel.php , it checking about permissions for all route even I did not call it in any route .
I don't want to apply this middleware on all route , just some of it .
this is my permission middleware's code

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use App\Rules;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use URL;

class Permissions  

 { 

   public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

       $rolename=Session::get('rule_name') ;
       $route = $request->path();

       $hasPermission = Rules::where('rule_name', 'superadmin')->where('allowed_pages', 'like', '%' . $route . '%') ->first();

            if (empty($hasPermission)) {

                echo 'Unauthorized.<a href="' . URL::to('/admin') . '">Go Back</a>';

                die();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my route file

```
Route::resource('Login', 'LoginController')->name('index','Login');

Route::resource('Backup', 'BackupController')->name('index','Backup');
```

as you see  I did not apply the middleware on these tow route , but the middleware is working with these tow routes
this is my kernel code

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
         'Permissions' => \App\Http\Middleware\Permissions::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

I want to run this middleware only by route like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'permissions'], function () {
  Route::resource('Backup', 'BackupController')->name('index','Backup');
}
```

thank you for advance 
best regards

Comment: don't apply in `web`  create indivdual and apply in single route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added your middleware to the middelwareGroup `web`, wich applies the middleware to every request comming in.

You need to add your middleware to the routes middleware array: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    ...
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

    // your own middlewares:
    'Permissions' => \App\Http\Middleware\Permissions::class,
];
```

You can than apply the middleware to specific routes:

```
Route::resource('Login', 'LoginController')->middleware('Permissions')->name('index','Login');
```

Answer (score 0):

you added inside `web` which is default middleware by laravel that's why it's applied in all route.

to register a middleware you need to add in   `protected $routeMiddleware = [ ]` array

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

    //custom middlewares:
    'Permissions' => \App\Http\Middleware\Permissions::class,
];
```

then only

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'permissions'], function () {
  Route::resource('Backup', 'BackupController')->name('index','Backup');
}
```

it will work